# Capture output of system command within a function in R

Tags: r, system

I'm working with a function in a package that uses `system2()` to run a command within the function. This particular command prints some stuff to standard out. I want to capture the output of that `system2()` call, however `capture.output()` does not work. I understand how to run `system2()` directly and capture the standard output, but not how to get it in this specific situation.

Simple example:

```
my_ls <- function() {
  system2("ls")
  return("Hello")
}
my_ls()
output <- capture.output(my_ls())
output
```

Comment: when in doubt `?system2`. you would have seen that using the argument `stdout = T` captures the output as a string.

Comment: the returned value of `my_ls` will always be just "Hello". There's no point in trying capture.output., Either use `return() around the `system2` call or reverse the order of those commands inside the function.

Comment: @JeremyS Yes, I am aware of that already. The point of my question is that the `system2` call is within a function in a package and I am not able to edit the function to set `stdout = T`, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: You are able to edit the function in a way. If the function is `MyFoo` then type `MyFoo`, note no brackets, and you get the R code of the function, copy it and make your changes and save it as a new function `MyFoo2` for example

Comment: @JeremyS Not a reliable solution. Package namespacing will break it, and if the user needs to call package::Foo and that calls something that calls something that calls package::Bar where the system2 call is you've got to edit Bar *in the package*, not a local copy.

Comment: @Spacedman, Surely the safer option is to just make a local copy of each of those functions and use them for this particular instance. You could add them to your own package or just source it if you want to use it often. I can't see how changing a third party package so that it is then different to everyone else's copy of that same package is more reliable, that seems like a road to future confusion to me.

Comment: Well you are just getting further down the rabbit hole if you do that. Better to get the whole package source code, modify it, make the stdout writing controlled by an option or something, and then *ask the maintainer to consider including your changes as an improvement*.

Comment: @Spacedman So, my takeaway from this is that there is no easy way to capture this output. I'd prefer to avoid this but, I'll just fork the repo on GitHub and change the function. As a side note: does anyone know the names for these two different places output is printed to, i.e. the stuff you can capture with `capture.output()` and the stuff you can't?

Comment: help(stdin) talks about "the console" and "the C-level 'stdin'" - `capture.output` gets "the console" output and `system2` outputs to "the C-level stdout' I reckon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution... But be warned, it works for me on Linux, might work on a Mac, and I doubt it works on Windows...

Create two `Rcpp` functions:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('void redir(){FILE* F=freopen("/tmp/capture.txt","w+",stdout);}')
cppFunction('void resetredir(){FILE* F=freopen("/dev/tty","w+",stdout);}')
```

The first will send everything to that file. The second will reset it. The problem is that interactively after the first you'll not be able to see anything. So beware...

So initially `system2` sends to the console:

```
> system2("echo", "hello")
hello
```

But wrapping a call in `redir`/`resetredir` sends it to the file:

```
> redir(); system2("echo","hello world this time") ; resetredir()
> # prompt returns!
```

Now we have:

```
$ cat /tmp/capture.txt 
hello world this time
```

and if this is the output from some other package you'll have to read it in with R's file I/O routines.

The dodgy bit is the use of `/dev/tty` in the reset code - I'm not sure it works on a Mac or Windows. If you don't care about resetting the stdout then skip it, and just make sure you know how to quite R without seeing what you type. I'm also unsure if this will work in RStudio which probably has a different concept of the console....

Comment: Very cool, thanks for this. You're right that `resetredir()` doesn't seem to work on a Mac/RStudio, but it doesn't matter for my purposes.

Comment: The function `redir()` works fine on Windows. `resetredir()`, however, should be defined as `cppFunction('void resetredir(){FILE* F=freopen("CON","w+",stdout);}')`